# Setting minimum Date on Angular validation

Tags: css, angular, validation, date

Hello guys I'm trying to make a minimum Date value in a Form. I'm using angular and for some reason that doesn't work I'll post my code:

Component:

```
minDate: Date;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private dataService: DataService, private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private matService: MatService) {
    this.dataService.getCompanyCouponResult(this.dataService.CouponIdForEdit).subscribe(res => {
      this.coupon = res;
      this.minDate = this.coupon.startDate;
      console.log(this.minDate);
    })
```

Output:

```
edit-coupon.component.ts:28 2014-02-13T22:00:00.000+0000
```

html:

```
  New end date:</p>
    <input type="date" formControlName="couponEndDate" min="{{minDate}}" >
```

now I do get the date, and I'm able to see it in console, but for some reason that doesn't apply on the "min" of couponEndDate. any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use pipes in it. Try with this:

```
<input type="date" formControlName="couponEndDate" min="{{todate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
```